# MVC 4 View doesnt recognize model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[EDIT]

```
@model LocationInfo (LocateIt.Models)

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just started working with MVC/NHibernate today by going through a little tutorial. Everything went fine until I tried to create a view out of my model through an ActionResult (Index). It seems that the view cant find the model and as I'm literally a Beginner I have no clue what to do.

Could you guys have a look at my code and tell me what I did wrong or at least give a clue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LocateIt.Models
{
    public class LocationInfo
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string LocationName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LocationDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string Street { get; set; }
        public virtual string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual short PLZ { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Rating { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LocateIt.Models;
using LocateIt.Models.NHibernate;

namespace LocateIt.Controllers
{
    public class LocationInfoController : Controller
    {
        LocationInfoRepository _repository;

        public LocationInfoController()
        {
            _repository = new LocationInfoRepository();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<LocationInfo> LocationInfo = _repository.GetLocation("Oberhausen");
            return View(LocationInfo);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Linq;

namespace LocateIt.Models.NHibernate
{
    public class LocationInfoRepository
    {

        public IList<LocationInfo> GetLocation(string city)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.Query<LocationInfo>().ToList();
            }

        }

        public void Save(LocationInfo objLocationInfo)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(objLocationInfo);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LocateIt.Models.NHibernate
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    var NHibernateConfig = new Configuration();
                    NHibernateConfig.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                        @"Models\NHibernate\Configuration\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                    NHibernateConfig.AddDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Models\NHibernate\Mappings")));
                    _sessionFactory = NHibernateConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
            return _sessionFactory;
            } 

        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping
xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
assembly="MVC4_Using_NHB"
namespace="MVC4_Using_NHB"
auto-import="true">
  <class name="MVC4_Using_NHB.Models.LocationInfo,MVC4_Using_NHB">
    <id name="Id" access="property" column="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="LocationName" access="property"
     column="LocationName" type="String"></property>
    <property name="LocationDescription" access="property"
    column="LocationDescription" type="String"></property>
    <property name="City" access="property"
    column="City" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Street" access="property"
    column="Street" type="String"></property>
    <property name="HouseNumber" access="property"
    column="HouseNumber" type="String"></property>
    <property name="PLZ" access="property"
    column="PLZ" type="Int16"></property>
    <property name="Rating" access="property"
     column="Rating" type="Int32"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What does " It seems that the view cant find the model" mean? Do you get any compilation error or runtime exception? What happens (or does not happen) which makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: I get the error: "the name 'model' does not exist in the current context" inside of the view.

Comment: You may have messed up the view. The view you posted seems like a layout but it seems like you tried to use it like a view. What's the name of that file?

Answer (score 1):

You're sending an IList into your view.  This will display a single item.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var info = _repository.GetLocation("Oberhausen").First();
    return View(info);
}
```

If you really want a list (e.g., you're going to display a table or some such), keep your action as is and change your view to:

```
@model IList<LocateIt.ModelsLocationInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the parentheses are doing in the model declaration. The syntax for @model should be:

```
@model Your.Namespace.ClassName
```

The in your code you use `Model`, not `model`.